# SSIS 2005 problems importing to nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have some XML files that I do a weekly import from for one of our systems. Four of the pieces of data in the XML range from 450 to 650 characters in length. I have tried everything I can think of but they always get truncated at around 255 characters. I tried setting the landing column to nvarchar(max), varchar(max), varchar(1000) and varchar(600) and none of this worked and I still get the same truncation. I inspected the XML files and the data there looks good. All the rest of the data comes in without truncation - just these four items have issues. I did find out googling around that SSIS considers nvarchar(max) and varchar(max) blob fields so I assume that is why they do not work correctly - but the others ??

Comment: How are you importing the data, straight from the file system, from another database via what kind of driver?,etc..

Comment: So you're slicing up the XML and putting individual element values in database fields?  Is that right?

Comment: @  Rawheiser - I am importing from text files on disk that contain the XML data. I use a XML source object in the SSIS package and an OLDB destination object. I have about 7 packages and they all work very well except for this problem.

Comment: @Ann L. - sort of. I'm not slicing it up but mapping it using XML Source object to OLDB Destination object in SSIS package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your Dataflow screen:

1. Look at your XML Source object.  Right click on it and select Advanced Editor.
2. Go to the Input and Output Properties tab
3. Expand the nodes until you see folders labeled External Columns and Output Columns.
4. Expand those.  You will probably find the 255 char length set in those.

Comment: Not doing a transform. Using XML Source object connect to OLDB Database object and mapping XML elements to table columns. The XML source object has an XSD file as one of its parameters.

Comment: What kind of control flow object are you using?  Data flow?

Comment: Yes dataflow. That is where the source and destination object reside.

Comment: OK, I've pulled up SSIS and revised my answer.  I was including data flows when I said "transform"; sorry for the confusion.